# How do I remove Windows 7 from a dual boot of Win7/Winxp without having to format the hard drive where the Windows 7 is?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, formatting, multi-boot

Can you help me? :( I've ruined my windows 7, that was installed in a dual-boot with windows xp, making it un-boot'able. So now I'm back to using my good old windows xp, and I want to remove windows 7 without formating the hard drive because there is too much important files in that drive and not enough space in other drives to back them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the safest thing is to leave the program files directory as you can't be sure what belongs to Windows XP and what belongs to Windows 7.

I would just delete the Windows folder (which ever one is from Windows 7 - I take it you know which one!).

Then, as you will have the Vista/7 Boot loader, I recommend you download [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) and remove the Windows 7 entry.

There are other ways that you could free up a little more space, but, I think this is the safest and easiest.

Answer (score 0):

Using Windows 7 boot manager to boot just Windows XP is a strange "solution".

You can always mark XP partition as active and run StartUp Repair using XP Recovery.

For more advanced users - you need to write:

1) XP MBR.

2) XP PBR to XP partition (should be active).

3) ensure ntldr, ntdetect.com and boot.ini on active.

4) ensure boot.ini has correct ARC paths for XP.