# Removing Windows 7 from a dual-booting system

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

I have installed Windows 7 and Windows 8 in my system and have been using them both. Now, after a long time, I have finally decided that it is time to move completely to Windows 8. Now, the problem is that I don't know how to move Windows 7 completely from my system. I want it to be removed completely and I don't want any programs ro details from the older OS. I can start everything afresh. Is there any software to do this? (Free perhaps)? Or, can someone suggest a method to move them manually and completely? Time isn't of importance and I can spend some time for my loving system. I did do some research. Is this enough : [Windows XP and Windows 7 : removing 7](https://superuser.com/questions/452140/how-do-i-remove-windows-7-from-a-dual-boot-of-win7-winxp-without-having-to-forma). I however think this is not a complete method.

Answer (score 0):

Is Windows 7 installed on a separate partition ? If yes then you could download [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) on a CD/DVD and then boot in the Live CD and with the help of the tool delete the partition Windows 7 is on. After that you could resize/expand the partition Windows 8 is on so that you don't leave unused partitions behind.

You could also do all this with the Windows Partition Manager called [Disk Management](http://www.howtogeek.com/101862/how-to-manage-partitions-on-windows-without-downloading-any-other-software/).There are plenty tutorials on the internet.

Comment: Yes. They are installed on separate partitions. If i format the drive,  I  think I will have the entry in the boot menu. Also, my system is using the boot manager from windows 7. (The Black screen one). How to change that? Sorry. I really don't know how to search these problems, if they have answered already.

Comment: The easiest way to do it is with GParted tool. Just delete the partition Windows 7 is on, after that resize and expand the partition Windows 8 is on (you don't need to do this) so you don't leave free space behind. If after that there is a problem with booting to your Windows 8 because Windows 7 boot menu was deleted just put your Windows 8 recovery CD/DVD and boot in to it and than select repair. Windows 8 will do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do anything you should make sure that any important files are backed up.

As Devid said you put [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) on a USB stick or CD/DVD and boot to it. Delete the Windows 7 partition and expand Windows 8 partition to fill the disk. Then reboot and remove the USB stick or CD/DVD. If the boot manager still shows the Windows 7, you should be able to remove it with the free version of [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/).